# Word to describe an informal, mutually beneficial interaction between two or more people

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

**Context**
Consider a language exchange group. In other words, people are teaching and learning foreign languages from each other. There are no monetary transactions.

I'm looking for a word that's friendly in tone to summarize this mutually beneficial concept. It should be more informal and "marketing" friendly than exchange. The best I've come up with is "mutual help," but it sounds a bit redundant to me.

**Sample sentence**
A community based on mutual help.

**Other options**
Reciprocity - too transactional
Mutual benefit - similar to mutual help and a bit sterile

Comment: It is somewhat unclear how exactly would the group you envisage operate. You reject *reciprocity* as 'too transactional', but your description of the group does not make it obvious what about it is not transactional. Given that you rejected *reciprocity*, I assume that you would also reject *barter*.

Answer (score 3):

The word [symbiosis](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/symbiosis) nicely captures the idea of cooperating for mutual benefit.

> a cooperative relationship (as between two persons or groups)

You could use it in a sentence like this:

> The members of a language exchange group are in symbiosis, teaching each other, and learning from each other at the same time.

Comment: *Symbiosis* usually stands for a relationship that is closer and more complex than what the OP describes.